# Proof by Mathematical Induction Query

Tags: proof-explanation

How would you go about proving something like  $$2^n > 5n^2$$ for all integers n>8

The part I do not understand is how to solve for $n=k+1$

Also solving for $n=k+1$ here:
$$2^n > 6n$$ for all integers n such that $n ≥ 5$

Any help is appreciated.

**Important Edit Info**: This question has been edited to fix a typo, so please ignore all answers stating that the problem is wrong, as they are referring to a previous, unedited version of the problem

Comment: Are you sure you got the question right?

Comment: $2n>5n^2\to 2>5n$ which is not true for any $n \in \Bbb N^*$.

Comment: I think you have just made up the example. You are in general looking for how to construct the inductive step ($k \to k+1$) of proofs by induction, right?

Comment: These statements are false, so you're unable to prove them, either with induction or any other means. Did you mean $2^n>6n$ in the second problem?

Comment: Many apologies, questions are now fixed.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581324/prove-by-induction-3n-gt-5n2-for-all-n-ge-4/4581384#4581384).

Answer (score 1):

The inductive step could look something like this:

Say that for some k > 8 we already have that:

$$2^k > 5k^2$$

Then

$$2^{k+1} = 2(2^k) > 2 (5k^2) = 10k^2 = 5k^2 + 5k^2 \geq 5k^2 + 5(2k+1) \geq 5k^2 + 10k + 5  = 5(k+1)^2$$

where we used the fact that $k^2 \geq 2k + 1$ for all $k \geq 3$ (Why? - to see this let $k \geq 3$ then: $k^2 = k*k \geq 3k = 2k + k \geq 2k +1$)

We conclude that:

> $$2^{k+1} > 5(k+1)^2$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I understand where you're coming from up to this point $$≥5k^2+5(2k+1)≥5k^2+10k+5=5(k+1)^2$$ How do get to this point?

Comment: You are welcome, I hope you found that helpful!

Comment: I also edited the answer to include the explanation of why $k^2 \geq 2k+1$

Comment: You are a star. Thanks a lot mate

Comment: You are very welcome. Just make sure to upvote all the answers you found helpful in the end.