# Prove that $2 \cdot 3^n>3 n^2+6$ for natural number $n>2$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that $2 \cdot 3^n>3 n^2+6$ for natural number $n>2$.

---

I tried putting different values of $n$ and saw as $n$ increases RHS is indeed greater than RHS, and also their difference increases too. I know exponential functions increases more rapidly, but how do I prove this rigorously using elementary techniques only (like basic inequality like AM-GM, cauchy schartwz etc and not calculus).

Comment: Hint: induction.

Comment: It is not true for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: Try n=1 it's not

Comment: By the way there exist N in N such that for all n>N this holds

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas I'm sorry I forgot to mention for all natural n>2

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581324/prove-by-induction-3n-gt-5n2-for-all-n-ge-4/4581384?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000#4581384) for the two *generic* approaches to proof by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $n\in\mathbb N$, then the given inequality holds for only $n≥3.$

The following proof uses the induction.

If $n=3$, then the inequality is correct.

Suppose that, the statemenet is also correct for $n=k$. Thus we have:

$$2\cdot 3^{k}-3k^2-6=a>0$$

Since $2\cdot 3^{k+1}>3(a+3k^2+6)$, then for $n=k+1$, we obtain:

$$\begin{align}&2\cdot 3^{k+1}-3(k+1)^2-6\\
>&~3(a+3k^2+6)-3(k+1)^2\\
=&~2k^2-2k+a+5\\
>&~2\left(k-\frac 12\right)^2+\frac 92\\
>&~0.\end{align}$$

By induction, the proof is completed.